# python manage.py collectstatic error: cannot find rest_framework bootstrap.min.css.map (from book 'Django for APIs')

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am reading the book 'Django for APIs' from 'William S. Vincent' (current edition for Django 4.0)

In chapter 4, I cannot run successfully the command python manage.py collectstatic.

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/django/django_for_apis/library/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/django/django_for_apis/library/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/django/django_for_apis/library/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/django/django_for_apis/library/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/django/django_for_apis/library/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/django/django_for_apis/library/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/django/django_for_apis/library/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 209, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/Users/my_name/Projects/django/django_for_apis/library/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 154, in collect
    raise processed
whitenoise.storage.MissingFileError: The file 'rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css.map' could not be found with <whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x102fa07f0>.

The CSS file 'rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css' references a file which could not be found:
  rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css.map

Please check the URL references in this CSS file, particularly any
relative paths which might be pointing to the wrong location.
```

I have the exact same settings like in the book in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]  # new
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"  # new
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"  # new
```

I couldn't find any explanation for it. maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you add `rest_framework` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes its in my INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update**: [DRF 3.14.0 now supports Django 4.1](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#3140). If you've added stubs to static as per below, be sure to remove them.

This appears to be related to Django 4.1: either downgrade to Django 4.0 or [simply create the following empty files in one of your static directories](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/8591#issuecomment-1220200518):

```
static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css.map
```

[There's a recent change to `ManifestStaticFilesStorage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/releases/4.1/#django-contrib-staticfiles) where it now attempts to replace source maps with their hashed counterparts.

Django REST framework has only recently added the bootstrap css source maps but is not yet released.

Comment: thanks! If I change to Django 4.0 it works

Comment: For any future readers. This is still the case.

Comment: The latest version of Django Rest Framework finally supports Django 4.1 https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#314x-series

Comment: I am using Django 4.1.1 and adding the empty files worked for me

Comment: Looks like this is still an issue with Django 4.2

Answer (score 0):

You have `STATIC_ROOT`  pointing to `BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"` and then `STATIC_URL = "static/"`. Make them point to the same static folder like this.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]
```

Comment: If I change the settings like this I get a

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.`

if I set STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "static", I get
`The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.`
if I set STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles", again I get
`The CSS file 'rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css' references a file which could not be found:
  rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css.map`

Comment: What version of Django are you using, this setting works for from version 2, and I have used it for version 4.0

Comment: I used Version 4.1. I tried now with 4.0 and is working